# runtime error. Problem with SMTP server

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Hi I am running the following program getting run time error.I have pasted below.

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.RecipientType;

public class MailWithPasswordAuthentication {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {
  new MailWithPasswordAuthentication().run();
 }

 private void run() throws MessagingException {
  Message message = new MimeMessage(getSession());

  message.addRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("abc@yahoo.co.in"));
  message.addFrom(new InternetAddress[] { new InternetAddress("xyz@gmail.com") });

  message.setSubject("the subject");
  message.setContent("the body", "text/plain");

  Transport.send(message);
 }

 private Session getSession() {
  Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();

  Properties properties = new Properties();
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.submitter", authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication().getUserName());
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "25");

  return Session.getInstance(properties, authenticator);
 }

 private class Authenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
  private PasswordAuthentication authentication;

  public Authenticator() {
   String username = "xyz@gmail.com";
   String password = "xyz";
   authentication = new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
  }

  protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
   return authentication;
  }
 }
}
```

Runtime error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. u8sm278510wbc.23

 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1829)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1368)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:886)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:191)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
 at MailWithPasswordAuthentication.run(MailWithPasswordAuthentication.java:26)
 at MailWithPasswordAuthentication.main(MailWithPasswordAuthentication.java:14)
```

Answer (score 2):

try to add `properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");`

Comment: Or in XML

<property key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable" value="true"/>

Answer (score 0):

Does google use port 25 for the smtp?

According to this [document by Google](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287) you need to use port 587 for TLS/STARTTLS or 465 for SSL.